# JDA Stream mp4 files to discord

Tags: java, discord, mp4

Is there a way to stream mp4 files with the java discord API? I searched on google but didn't find anything.
I want to write a bot that can stream mp4 files to discord channels so other people can watch it.

Answer (score 4):

Discord bots cannot use video at all. This is intentionally blocked for bots because the developers can't provide a stable API for video streaming due to its complexity.